# PostgreSQL: Exclude geometries on the next query if it intersects on the previous one

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have this query to get the number of geoms that intersect in another geom:

```
SELECT  count(evidensapp_polystructures.brgy_locat) AS high,
        evidensapp_polystructures.brgy_locat AS barangay,
        evidensapp_polystructures.municipali AS municipality
FROM evidensapp_floodhazard
INNER JOIN evidensapp_polystructures
      ON st_intersects(evidensapp_floodhazard.geom, evidensapp_polystructures.geom) 
      AND evidensapp_floodhazard.hazard= 'High'
GROUP BY evidensapp_polystructures.brgy_locat, evidensapp_polystructures.municipali;
```

As you noticed, its `hazard` is equal to `High`. **I wanted to get also the number of geoms that intersect with the `hazard` value: `Medium` and `Low`. But, if a certain geometry intersects already in `High`,exclude in it `Medium` query and same goes with `Low` exclude those geometry that intersects in `High` and `Medium`.**

I have this idea, maybe use [CASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html) or I need to get the `id` of the geometry then try `NOT IN` in query but don't know how to do it. Probably because I'm new in PostgreSQL or any database work.

Here's a sample result of the query above:
[image]

The intended result should be like this:

[image]

Table details:

```
CREATE TABLE evidensapp_floodhazard (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  hazard character varying(6) NOT NULL,
  date_field character varying(60),
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,32651),
  CONSTRAINT evidensapp_floodhazard_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX evidensapp_floodhazard_geom_id
  ON evidensapp_floodhazard USING gist (geom);

ALTER TABLE evidensapp_floodhazard CLUSTER ON evidensapp_floodhazard_geom_id;

CREATE TABLE evidensapp_polystructures (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  bldg_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  bldg_type character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  brgy_locat character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  municipali character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  province character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,32651),
  CONSTRAINT evidensapp_polystructures_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX evidensapp_polystructures_geom_id
  ON evidensapp_polystructures USING gist (geom);

ALTER TABLE evidensapp_polystructures CLUSTER ON evidensapp_polystructures_geom_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is little you can do with the strings "High", "Medium" and "Low" in terms of comparison, you have to use sub-queries. A solution with some CTE's would probably be the cleanest:

```
WITH hi AS (
  SELECT ps.id, ps.brgy_locat, ps.municipali
  FROM evidensapp_polystructures ps
  JOIN evidensapp_floodhazard fh ON fh.hazard = 'High'
                                 AND ST_Intersects(fh.geom, ps.geom)
), med AS (
  SELECT ps.id, ps.brgy_locat, ps.municipali
  FROM evidensapp_polystructures ps
  JOIN evidensapp_floodhazard fh ON fh.hazard = 'Medium'
                                 AND ST_Intersects(fh.geom, ps.geom)
  EXCEPT SELECT * FROM hi
), low AS (
  SELECT ps.id, ps.brgy_locat, ps.municipali
  FROM evidensapp_polystructures ps
  JOIN evidensapp_floodhazard fh ON fh.hazard = 'Low'
                                 AND ST_Intersects(fh.geom, ps.geom)
  EXCEPT SELECT * FROM hi
  EXCEPT SELECT * FROM med
)
SELECT brgy_locat AS barangay, municipali AS municipality, high, medium, low
FROM (SELECT brgy_locat, municipali, count(*) AS high
      FROM hi
      GROUP BY 1, 2) cnt_hi
FULL JOIN (SELECT brgy_locat, municipali, count(*) AS medium
      FROM med
      GROUP BY 1, 2) cnt_med USING (brgy_locat, municipali)
FULL JOIN (SELECT brgy_locat, municipali, count(*) AS low
      FROM low
      GROUP BY 1, 2) cnt_low USING (brgy_locat, municipali);
```

In the three CTE's you first identify rows that fall in the "high" hazard category, then those in the "medium" hazard category but `EXCEPT` those that are already in the "high" category, then those in the "low" hazard category except those listed as "high" or "medium". In the main query you then join the 3 CTE's with the count per barangay and municipality calculated in a sub-query from each of the CTE's. A `FULL JOIN` is used such that barangays and municipalities that do not have structures in the "high" hazard class also show up in the results.

Comment: Thanks for this, how do I make the result in one row? same rows if same barangay.

Comment: Which version of PG are you using?

Comment: It is 9.3. The result is correct based on the intended ouput but it is not in one row even if the barangay is the same. BTW, thanks for explaining it well.

Comment: See updated answer: use JOINs instead of UNIONs. In 9.4 you could have used the `FILTER` clause with the `count()` aggregate, hence my question. You should always indicate your PG version when asking a question.

Comment: Ok..thanks..I takes almost 15 mins(874043 ms) to get the result. But anyway, I'll research more on how to optimize it. Your answer will serve as my basis.